# Array can't be coerced into Float

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have an 'Array can't be coerced into Float' error appearing in my rails application due to the <%= "%.1f" % (r.lint/@compare*100) %> line in my view. Any help would be appreciated.

View

```
<% @result.each do |r| %>
<%= "%.2f" % (r.lint/227) %></br>
<%= "%.2f" % (r.lint/227/2.47) %></td>
<%= "%.1f" % (r.lint/@compare*100) %>
<% end %>
```

Controller

```
def trial
 @result = Result.where('trial_id' => params[:trial_id]).order('lint DESC')
 @compare = Trial.where('trial_id' => params[:trial_id]).pluck(:comp_lint)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems to be because `@compare` is an array of `comp_lint` of `Trial`.

If in your case it will always be one then do `.first` on `@compare`

```
@compare = Trial.where('trial_id' => params[:trial_id]).pluck(:comp_lint).first
```

otherwise if you want to sum up all the comp_lint's  then do

```
@compare = Trial.where('trial_id' => params[:trial_id]).pluck(:comp_lint).sum
```

Comment: Thanks Amit. Works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

Your `@compare` is actually an array of `[:comp_lints]` (whatever that is).
So when you do, `r.lint/@compare`, Ruby tries to convert @compare (Array) to a Float. Which cannot happen.

You need to select the appropriate value from `@compare` and perform the arithmetic.